# Redis Cache MYSQL results

Tags: caching, redis, analytics

I wish to store PDO results in redis cache so from online resources I gathered i do this.

```
$domain = 'www.example.com';



function getStat($domain) {
global $pdo;
global $redis;

$statement = "SELECT * FROM mc_visitor_session WHERE website = \'$domain\'";

$hash = md5($statement);

if (!$redis->get($hash . '-cache')) {

            $query = $pdo->query($domain);

            if ($result = $query->execute()) {

                $record = $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $redis->set($hash . '-cache', serialize($record));
                $redis->expire($hash . '-cache', 86400);

                echo 'RESULT FROM MYSQL';
                pretty_print($record);
            }

        }

        $results = unserialize($redis->get($hash . '-cache'));
        //will show this if it's already in cache.
        echo 'RESULT FROM REDIS';
        pretty_print($results);
 }


     getStat($domain);
```

As you can see the above code works well. However I wish to work it with pdo prepared statements instead of using pdo query without preparing and safely executing the queries. But I need to get the hash from the query statement as well to be use as the key in redis.

This is just one of the query i want to cache with redis and other queries contains more than 1 WHERE statement which requires multiple PDO Bind Parameter.

This may not be the best way to do it so may I ask for suggestions on how I can improve this to make it safer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw this ["Smart" Caching System using PDO and Memcache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118762/smart-caching-system-using-pdo-and-memcache) elsewhere on SO.

Wrap your PDO call inside a function that will hash the statement and an array of parameters.

```
$name = 'querycache-'.md5(serialize(array($sql, $params)));
```

You also need to ask yourself if fine-tuning your database, using proper indexes and letting it use its own caching system won't be faster than caching to Redis.

Comment: Thank you. I was following tutorials so I'm a little thick when it came to the redis key. I now just implement other form of redis key hash base on userid or groupid etc. Caching of a single mysql query is not efficient as you mention. But thanks to your codes now I just cache the entire request, which may consist of 15-20 mysql queries, into one json string in the redis-cache for fast access.

Answer (score 0):

Write `$query = $pdo->query($statement);` instead of `$query = $pdo->query($domain);`